# Arrarylist to hbox to gridpane

Tags: arraylist, javafx, gridpane, hbox

Thank You For Taking The Time To Help Me. I Am Working On Making A Game Board And I Would Like to Have My ArrayList Of Images Added Into an hbox and then Into a gridpane or tilepane which ever you would think is better. I think tilepane. I am trying to use a loop to loop through arraylist to make the image views. But ass you can see i get no results. Please Help Thank You Again For The Help. The method I am trying to get to work is addGridPane. The primarystage also has my main menu and is of type borderpane. I have the gridpane centered within the borderpane.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;

public class Runner extends Application {
    static ArrayList<PlayerMove> moves = new ArrayList<PlayerMove>();
    static ArrayList<Image> tileImages = new ArrayList<>();
    static HBox currentMoves = getHBoxCurrentMoves("PLAYER MOVES:", moves, 0, 0);
    static VBox playerBox = getVBoxTextList();//red
    static VBox playerBox1 = getVBoxTextList1();//black
    static HBox imageTiles = setTileImages(tileImages);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

    public static VBox getVBoxTextList2(String TitleName) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(50, 50, 50, 100));
        vbox.setSpacing(8);
        vbox.setPrefHeight(100);
        vbox.setPrefWidth(100);
        Text title = new Text(TitleName);
        title.setFill(Color.rgb(178, 0, 0));
        title.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
        vbox.getChildren().add(title);
        vbox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #b20000;" + "-fx-background-color: black;");

        return vbox;
    }

    public static VBox getVBoxTextList() {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vbox.setSpacing(8);
        vbox.setPrefHeight(100);
        //vbox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #b20000;" + "-fx-background-color: #8b5a2b;");
        //vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('redplayer.png')");
        vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('redplayer.png')");
        Image image = new Image("redplayer.png");
        ImageView redplayer = new ImageView();
        redplayer.setImage(image);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(redplayer);
        vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        return vbox;
    }

    public static VBox getVBoxTextList1() {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vbox.setSpacing(8);
        vbox.setPrefHeight(100);
        //vbox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #b20000;" + "-fx-background-color: black;");
        //vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('blackplayer.png')");
        Image image = new Image("blackplayer.png");
        ImageView blackplayer = new ImageView();
        blackplayer.setImage(image);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(blackplayer);
        vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        return vbox;
    }
    public static HBox setTileImages(ArrayList<Image> myImages){
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        ArrayList<Image> temp = myImages;
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
            ImageView boardImage = new ImageView(temp.get(i));
        }
        return hbox;
    }

    public GridPane addGridPane(ArrayList<PlayerMove> myMoves, ArrayList<Image> myImages) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: pink;");
        grid.setHgap(20);
        grid.setVgap(20);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(30, 300, 30, 300));
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        ArrayList<PlayerMove> temp = myMoves;
        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;

                //I would like to have the arraylist of images added in to an hbox
                //then into a gridpane making it get the string of everyimage to compare
                ArrayList<Image> tempImage = myImages;
                for(int m = 0; m < tempImage.size(); m++){
                    Image image = new Image(tempImage.get(m).toString());

                    ImageView picture = new ImageView();
                    picture.setFitHeight(145);
                    picture.setFitWidth(145);
                    picture.setImage(image);
                    grid.add(picture,col,row);
                    hbox.getChildren().add(picture);
            }
        return grid;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Niya Game Board");
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        border.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #999C9E;");
        GridPane layout = addGridPane(moves, tileImages);

        //ArrayList<Image> tileImages = new ArrayList<>();
            tileImages.add(new Image ("bird&cloud.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("bird&computer.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("bird&dragon.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("bird&flower.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("bird&leaf.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("bird&sun.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("bird&tiger.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("cloud&computer.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("cloud&dragon.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("cloud&flower.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("cloud&leaf.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("cloud&sun.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("cloud&tiger.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("computer&dragon.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("computer&flower.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("computer&leaf.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("computer&sun.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("computer&tiger.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("dragon&flower.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("dragon&leaf.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("dragon&sun.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("dragon&tiger.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("flower&leaf.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("flower&sun.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("flower&tiger.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("leaf&sun.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("leaf&tiger.jpg"));
            tileImages.add(new Image ("sun&tiger.jpg"));
        ArrayList<HBox> hboxList = new ArrayList<>();

        VBox menu = getVBoxTextList2("Welcome To The Niya Game Board");
        StackPane border2 = new StackPane();
        BorderPane border1 = new BorderPane();
        border1.setTop(menu);
        border2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        border2.setPrefSize(800, 800);
        Image img = new Image("main.jpg");
        ImageView background = new ImageView(img);
        border1.setCenter(background);

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20, 55, 20, 55));
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");

        Button button1 = new Button("PLAY GAME");
        button1.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 Arial; FontWeight.BOLD; -fx-base: #b6e7c9; -fx-text-fill: white;");
        button1.setPrefSize(200, 70);
        button1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                Scene sc = new Scene(border);
                primaryStage.setScene(sc);
                primaryStage.show();
            }
        });

        Button button2 = new Button("SAVED GAMES");
        button2.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 Arial; FontWeight.BOLD; -fx-base: #b6e7c9; -fx-text-fill: white;");
        button2.setPrefSize(200, 70);
        button2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Loading Saved Games...");
            }
        });
        button2.setOnAction(e -> {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            if (file != null) {
                Path path = Paths.get(file.toURI());
                Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
                List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charset)) {
                    lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    return;
                }
                for (String s : lines) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

            }
        });
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2);

        border1.setLeft(hbox);

        border.setCenter(layout);
        border.setLeft(playerBox);
        border.setRight(playerBox1);
        border.setBottom(currentMoves);
        Scene sc1 = new Scene(border1);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc1);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```